# Pass data to Socket.io callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
client.on('message', function(obj){});
```

This works fine, but I am trying to avoid nesting, so I take the callback function out like so:

```
client.on('message', doThis(obj));

function doThis(obj) {}
```

But this gives me an error saying obj is undefined.

How do I pass the message data to the callback function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
client.on('message', doThis);

function doThis(obj) {}
```

`f(doThis)` is the correct syntax. `f(doThis(arg))` is the wrong syntax.

The latter is calling `doThis` immediately with the argument `arg` (which doesn't exist yet).

That's why it says `obj` is undefined because your calling `doThis` immediatly.

What `f(doThis)` does is passes the function on instead of the return value of the function